# Matrix acting on a tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

What does it mean for a matrix to act on a tensor product? I think there is a disconnect between vocabulary I am using and vocabulary the professor is using. Specifically, I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix acting on the tensor product of several 2 dimensional vector spaces, and I am asked to compute the determinant and trace of the matrix acting on the tensor product.

Comment: What class is this for?  That might be a helpful clue

Comment: Your professor might mean the tensor power of the map.  That is, we define
$$
(A \otimes \cdots \otimes A)(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n) = (Av_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes (Av_n)
$$
which extends to a linear map on the tensor product of the spaces.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom this is for a linear algebra class. And thank you, that makes a lot of sense.